# PDO MySQL load count for each day into an array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, pdo

I have a voting voting system, people vote for something using my website. I record every vote, each vote is a row in the table. I.e:

```
| id  |  ip  | date                       |
-------------------------------------------
|  1  | ::1  | 2014-05-22 20:31:16.000000 |
```

Since I save the date, It's possible to base it on days in this month.

I have a line graph, which will display the days that has the biggest amount of votes (sorted from lowest to highest).

How can I load the day number (e.g 1,2,3,4) and the amount of votes so it will be stored in an array like this:

```
[
  1 => 104,
  2 => 234,
  3 => 636,
  4 => 105
];
```

**So if the vote was made on the same day, it will add it to the count of that day.**

where the key is the day number and value is the amount of votes in that day.

*I am using PDO*, how can I load it exactly like that?

Comment: What are you having problems with, the sql or the php?

Comment: i hope you know IP does not identify a unique person. many peopl can share 1 IP address and one person can be seen as coming from multiple addresses

Comment: @jeroen Building the query to load COUNT by day.

Comment: use `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR)` to get results in key => value format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following query returns your desired data

```
SELECT DAY(`date`), COUNT(*)
FROM `your table`
WHERE YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(`date`) = MONTH(NOW())
GROUP BY DAY(`date`)
```

wrap it with `$pdo->query(...)` and call `fetchAll()` on the result.

You might want to tweek the `WHERE` constraint of the query a bit, to use the `date` column without function calls on it (so the query can use indices), for example with `date BETWEEN ... AND ...`. This is left as an exercise for you.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard i can't understand your rollback! `PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR` is part of this answer...

Comment: i won't duplicate the answer when only need is one parameter. if i have the power to edit answer, i will edit the answer!!!

Comment: Suit yourself @ThiagoFrança but when the changes affect the answer significantly you can expect that someone might not approve them or roll them back. As I said, there is no need for duplication, just a comment to the poster who provided the answer. There can be several variants in `fetchAll()`, so the one that you put there would just be a suggestion.

Comment: Part of the question is: "How can I load the day number (e.g 1,2,3,4) and the amount of votes, so it will be stored in an **array where the key is the day number and value is the amount of votes**" The way with PDO to this is the use of constant `PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR` in `fetchAll()`, even with all the variants for `fetchAll()`, the one that meets is that.

Answer (score -4):

you can do something linke this:

```
$year = 2014;
$month = 01;
$array = array();
for($day = 1; $day <= 31; $day++)
{
    $date = "$year.$month.$day";
    $array[$day] = execute sql string "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE date > $date 00:00:00 AND date < $date 23:59:59"
}
```

Comment: 1 query for every day, please no

Comment: I know but someone voted the first solution down so I wrote someting easyer

Comment: its just a bad idea, i suggest you delete it